# q(i,j)=X x P1(i,j) + (1-X) x P2(i,j) :how to code it in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

`q(i,j)=X x P1(i,j) + (1-X) x P2(i,j)`

where P1 and P2 are two input images and X is any constant value ,e.g X=0.5
how to write the code for it ?

Comment: what have you tried?  Do you need help with inputting images or with calculating `q`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming P1 and P2 are stored in matrices and have the same size, you can just write

```
q = X * P1 + (1-X) * P2
```

To read in images you want to use `imread`

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [IMLINCOMB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imlincomb.html) function to compute linear combination of images:

```
q = imlincomb(x,P1, 1-x,P2);
```